# Is it possible to approve() multiple spenders at once?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, erc-20

I was wondering whether it possible to call this function

```
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success)
```

with multiple spenders at once (for example, 1000 different spenders)?

If yes, will it consume the same amount of gas as calling it for 1 spender x 1000 times?

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to call this function {} with multiple spenders at once

No, it is not.

**Default** function receives only one address as an input.

```
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }
```

---

> (for example, 1000 different spenders)?

You can do it manually. The mapping of mappings

`mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) internal allowed;`

gives you opportunity to approve multiple addresses to spend allowed amount of tokens from one address.

---

> If yes, will it consume the same amount of gas as calling it for 1 spender x 1000 times?

No, even if the call was from one function you are still paying 21000 gas + 1000 x `SSTORE operation (20000 gas if _spender is not in mapping / 5000 gas otherwise)`.

Comment: Roman, thank you very much for your quick reply! Unfortunately, due to my non-existent experience in solidity (and programming in general), it is hard for me to figure out how exactly would I go about implementing this feature in my code (which is standard ERC20 token code from OpenZeppelin). So as I understand I would need to create the mapping of mappings and then create a new function similar to Approve?

Comment: Mapping `allowed` is already declared in OpenZeppelin StandardToken.sol. Yes, you would need to implement this function and add it to this contract or to the new contract with StandardToken inheritance.